# How to generate the Schema Objectsfrom xsd present in external jar file using maven

Tags: jaxb

I had prepared some xsd under src\main\resources folder structure and created a.jar file now I want to generate the scheam objects for xsd in a.jar in another application  like generateSource application can anybody help me in writing the maven plugin in pom.xml file
like what all dependencies and plugins required.

Answer (score 1):

1st you need to extract the jar which contains XSD using maven-dependency-plugin like this.

```
<plugin>
<!-- Unpack the jar into target directory -->
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${unpack.directory}</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            <includeGroupIds>com.companyname</includeGroupIds>
            <includeArtifactIds>jarname</includeArtifactIds>
            <excludes>**/*.html,samples/**</excludes>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Later you need to use maven-jaxb2-plugin to convert extracted xsds to java classes as mentioned below.

```
<plugin>
<!-- Convert XSD to java classes using jaxb plugin -->
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.8.2</version>
<configuration>
    <extension>true</extension>
    <generateDirectory>${generated.source.directory}</generateDirectory>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
    <id>Generate java-from-schema</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>${unpack.directory}/XXX</schemaDirectory>
        <catalog>${unpack.directory}/catalog</catalog>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <schemaInclude>aaa/*.xsd</schemaInclude>
            <schemaInclude>bbb/*.xsd</schemaInclude>
            <schemaInclude>ccc/*.xsd</schemaInclude>
        </schemaIncludes>
    </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [separate schema compilation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Separateschemacompilation) documentation.